# Reduce the mongodb nested data structure result into a list

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

When i am running an aggregation query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind":"$blocks"},
    {"$unwind":"$blocks.ports"},
    {"$match":{"blocks.ports.portType.function":"input"}},
    {$project:{_id:0, port:"$blocks.ports"}}
])
```

on this document

```
{ "blocks" : { "ports" : {"portType" : { "function" : "input"}  }  }  }
```

i am getting the result in format of nested structure

```
{"ports":{<first-key>: <first-value>, ...}},{"ports":{<first-key>: <first-value>, ...}},...
```

Is there a way to omit this nested structure and directly get a list of ports with all the fields ?

```
{<first-key>: <first-value>, ...},{<first-key>: <first-value>, ...}
```

Comment: please provide your sample mongo document and desired output you want.

Comment: The expected output is not a valid BSON document, could you fix that ?

Comment: use reducers for that?